# How to automatically allow Current location in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, uialertview, cllocationmanager

I am working in iPhone application, Using `CLLocationManager` to develop my application, when I run the application and its show one alert view like "Would like to use Your current location".
Then prees Ok to continue it.

But I don't want to show an alert view, is it possible to let the app track the user's location without a prompt?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This alert view is mandatory and there is no way to avoid it, unless you somehow create your own location tracking client, however any access of location without a prompt is prohibited by the guidelines and Apple will reject your app.

The reason is so users are aware that you are tracking your location -- security and preference.

Why would you want to avoid the alert view in the first place?

Comment: I m making an application and ask user to fill a signup form. in that form I have made a tick mark if selected use user location otherwise not. so I want to prevent this popup otherwise I have to remove that line from my signup page.

Answer (score 3):

This dialog is promtped by the system for privacy and security reasons. If you somehow manage to avoid this and access location data, your app will be surely rejected during the App Store Approval Process. Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: If I want to stop the user, if he press Don't Allow button, because it is necessary to use his current location.

Answer (score 3):

No, I am 100% sure it's not possible to prevent this alert view

but I think when you click on Don't allow then your CLLocationManager is stop but you can again give it to allow from iphone setting

Comment: How to allow from iPhone setting?

Comment: Settings->Privacy->Location Services   on or off

Comment: And in Location Services there are lots of Application those running in your device which are using location services, you can also on or off those particular application's location services